# Konqueror 3.5.9 does not allow comments

Tags: feature-request, browsers

I am a registered user of Stackoverflow and use Konqueror 3.5.9 (from Debian lenny/KDE) regularly. With that browser, the comment text field does not open up when I press 'add comment'. 
With Firefox/Iceweasel does it work.

I suggest a comptibility warning for users of Konqueror.

Comment: Commented with Konqueror 4.4.2

Comment: @json: Many thanks. I will upgrade to Debian squeeze as soon as possible.

Comment: no need to rush, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, Konqueror 3.5.9 is the equivalent to Firefox 1.5 or Internet Explorer 4/5.

Try using another browser from Debian Lenny that works better with SO.

Furthermore, I'd argue that users of Debian stable are already used to websites not working completely and are technically competent enough to understand the problem and how to solve it.

---

You can install Firefox 3.5 on Debian 5.0 (Lenny) this way:

- [Download firefox-3.5.tar.bz2](http://go2.wordpress.com/?id=725X1342&site=putolinux.wordpress.com&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.mozilla.org%2F%3Fproduct%3Dfirefox-3.5%26os%3Dlinux%26lang%3Des-ES&sref=http%3A%2F%2Fputolinux.wordpress.com%2F2009%2F07%2F01%2Fcomo-instalar-el-puto-firefox-3-5-en-debian-gnulinux-5-0-lenny%2F)
- Extract and copy to `/usr/lib` as root.

  ```
  cd Desktop && cp -rv firefox /usr/lib
  ```
- Create symlink on `/usr/bin` to the Firefox executable.

  ```
  cd /usr/bin
  ln -s /usr/lib/firefox/firefox firefox3.5
  ```

By now you have a working firefox on your machine. Now to add the menu shortcut on KDE 3.5

1. Go to Menu settings > Menu Editor > New Item.
2. Complete as you please and on the `command` line write `/usr/bin/firefox3.5` or `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`.

Comment: @json. Many thanks. I use Firefox as an alternative. 
My misconception was that I have a  reputation too low to comment on my answer. Only after reading the FAQ I learned that commenting own questions and answers is possible with rep 1.